In reality, how does channel estimation for multi-user work?
At BS, for antenna $m$, I see some papers and some code that presents the received signal $Y_{nm}$ from user $n$ as a $K \times N_{\text{symbol}}$ matrix ($K$ is the number of subcarriers, $N_{\text{symbol}}$ is the number of OFDM symbols in 1 slot). For the channel between antenna $m$ from the BS and the user $n$, $H_{nm}$ is also in the size $K\times N_{\text{symbol}}$, and the transmitted from the UE $n$, $X_{n}$ is also in the size $K \times N_{\text{symbol}}$.
Then, the estimated channel (in the frequency domain) is $H_{nm} = Y_{nm} / X_{nm}$ - element-wise.
What I am confused here is that, in reality, how can we get $Y_{nm}$? As I understand, the received signal at antenna $m$ of the BS is already the sum of all the signals from all users, $Y_{m} = Y_{1m} +\ldots+ Y_{nm} +\ldots+ Y_{Nm}$. I also read about precoding and decoding, but it requires the estimated channel for the precoding? I feel this is so confusing, can you please explain this to me?
